# Function with single formula that have non zero value only in one small range

Tags: functions

Is it possible to have one formula for a function $f(x)$ that will look like on this picture:

[image]

Without cases for $x < x_0$, $x >= x_0\space and\space x <= x_1$,$x > x_1$.

The formula should be just $f(x) = ...$ it can contain derivative and any algebraic transformation of $x$ and values in range $<x_0, x_1>$ should be a line and outside should be 0.

Another question is it possible to transform a function $f(x)$ to have function $g(x)$ that will have 0 outside of range $<x_0,x_1>$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $x<y$ is equivalent to $y-x>0$ and therefore $\frac{\left(y-x\right)+\left|y-x\right|}{2\left|y-x\right|}=1$.

Now let $c(x,y)=\frac{\left(x-y\right)+\left|x-y\right|}{2\left|x-y\right|}=\cases{{1, y<x}\\{0,y>x}}$.

Then you can write $g(x)=c(x, x_0)\cdot c(x_1,x)\cdot f(x)$ which is equal to $f(x)$ if and only if $x_0<x<x_1$, it is $0$ if and only if $x<x_0$ or $x>x_1$ and undefined if and only if $x=x_0$ or $x=x_1$ (because of the denominators in $c(x,y)$).

Comment: That's awesome, I use wolfram alpha and I've got just what I wanted http://bit.ly/W0jkzm, thanks.