# Is this interpolation, does it have a name?

Tags: approximation, interpolation

I was waching Signle Variable Calculus MIT lectures (I stop on 9 about linear approximation) I was also learn interpolation at my university and I thought that I'll create my own equation for interpolation to better understand it. I've ask this question [Function with single formula that have non zero value only in one small range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865958/function-with-single-formula-that-have-non-zero-value-only-in-one-small-range) which give me all I need.

So I came up with this equation:

$ I(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{(x-x_i)+|x-x_i|}{2|x-x_i|} * \frac{(x_{i+1}-x)+|x_{i+1}-x|}{2|x_{i+1}-x|} * (f'(x_i)*x+f(x_i)) $

Is this the interpolation that interpolate using tangent lines? Does someone else discovered this type of interpolation, if it's correct, does it have a name?

I've use wolfram alpha to test: http://bit.ly/Waq7qJ instead of tangent lines I just use lines $x+b$.

**UPDATE**:

I have a function and have list of $x$ and can calculate list of $y$ out of them so I have pairs of $x_i$ and $f(x_i)$ which are numbers. 2 fractions in equations are just cut function that draw only fraction in parantheses, the fraction is $<x_i, x_{i+1}>$ If I add 2 ranges that are next to each other I'll get line without breaks.

The part in parenteses is my line function, $f'(x_i)$ is the tangent of the line (a number) so its $a$ in $a*x+b$ so if I multiply it by $x$ I have a line (a function so it also make $I(x)$ a function). To have the line in correct place I need to shift it so I add $f(x_i)$ so it's in correct place.

Comment: You can't plug in any of the points $x_i$, which is a... problem. You should probably use the "max" function instead of that complicated (albeit clever I'll admit) expression with absolute values - that would make things much clearer. Also, would you mind posting an outline of your derivation for the above equation?

Comment: I have looked more closely, your formula is definitely incorrect - please explain what you did to derive that.

Comment: @NotNotLogical I've updated the question.

Comment: @NotNotLogical I can write a computer program that will calulate this. So how it's a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I poorly read your post; it turns out that your idea is correct.

As far as I understand it, you are creating a function which connects the points $(x_i,f(x_i))$ together with straight line segments. A few notes:

1. I think the linear part is wrong. It should be $$f(x_i)+f'(x_i)\cdot(x-x_i)$$ since you add on the change, equal to rate of change $f'(x_i)$ times change $\Delta x=x-x_i$, to the value $f(x_i)$.
2. Your formula returns $0$ outside the range $(x_0,x_n)$. Not that that's a bad thing, just something to note. More importantly,
3. Your formala (as written) fails to exist at the points $x_i$ themselves, because then you are dividing by $0$. I think you should replace expressions of the form $$\frac{a+|a|}{2a}$$ with simply $$\text{sign}(x):=\begin{cases} 1&x>0 \\ 0&x\le 0\end{cases}$$ which returns the same results, and still exists when $a=0$ (also, I just noticed that you are using absolute value signs in the denominator, which I do not think is necessary). However, in this case that does not solve the problem because now the formula would return $0$ at the interpolation "sample" points. The only solution I can think of (for getting an expression in closed form) is to use a limit like so: $$\lim_{z\to a^+}\frac{z+|z|}{2z}$$ 
   When $a=0$ this returns $1$ which is what we want.
4. As to names, you may want to research "spline interpolation" - this is more or less a simple case of that.